# How do planet adjacency effects work?

Tags: stellaris

I've just started a new game, and am exploring the various options.  I've run into the planetary details screen.  Each tile can support one building, and one population.  Thing is, I noticed these little + arrows next to some buildings, and hovering over them gives me adjacency bonuses.

[image: Adjacency bonus example]

What causes this?  Is it specific buildings that improve the spaces around them?  Is there a list of adjacency combos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only buildings with adjacency bonuses are the Planetary Capital line of buildings (and their upgrades) starting from the Planetary Administration (after upgrading the Reassembled Ship Shelter).

In this case, as per their descriptions, they provide +1/+2/+3 to production of adjacent Minerals, Energy, and Food. Sorry, scientists!

These 3 are listed on the [Stellaris Wiki](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Buildings), and there don't appear to be any others.

Comment: I believe there are other special "buildings" that give adjacency bonuses. I've seen conquered natives placed in reservations to give society research bonus.

Comment: @svick Tileblockers and events, yes. In general gameplay though? Not so much.

Comment: Although they aren't technically buildings, some hazards provide adjacency bonuses. I put some pre-sentient natives in reservations, and they provide a +3 society bonus to any adjacent buildings that *already produce soceity*. Some hazards do this as well. You can tell what the adjacency bonus will be when you click on the tile, the same place you would go to clear the hazard.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this dev article](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/stellaris-dev-diary-9-planets-resources.891510/),

> Buildings can also be constructed in tiles, and they often have adjacency bonuses for the resource they are producing. Therefore it will be advantageous to construct your power plants in proximity to each other, to achieve optimal efficiency.

so the adjacency bonus should come from buildings that produce the same resource in an adjacent tile.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? So far I've only noticed bonuses from my capitol building.

Answer (score 0):

Its because that tile (the tile that is providing the adjacency bonus) is where you first sent down your calony ship to colonize the planet, or in this case as it is your capital planet it is actually the planetary administration, or capital of the planet. The capital of the planet is what provides the adjacency bonus. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I understand it was my administration building.  But it can't be the only building doing that, and it, by itself, doesn't tell us much.